# pinescript indicator, sometimes label not shown

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I have a script that returns the alert and plotting. The idea was to place a limit long position and after low < limit price its open position and then close on tp/sl. however, I stuck with... I don't know why but the script is not consistent. sometimes it works on 1h, but the label won't appear on 1m timeframe. if I comment the wickCond or volumCond it will work (open and close label appear), but I'm not sure where the problem really is. any help or suggestion would be appreciated

```
indicator("Volume Candle Limit Long", overlay=true)

periodo = input(20,'Period')
fator=input.float(1.25,'Proportion to average:(1,25 = 125% of average', minval=0)
up = close > open 
down= open > close
pesado = volume>(ta.ema(volume,periodo)*fator)
barcolor((pesado and up)? color.lime:(pesado and down)?color.red:up?color.silver:color.gray)

//====================================================================================================
useSL               = input(true, "Use stop Loss")
StopTrailPerc       = input.float(title="Trail Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
use_SL_Trigger      = input(true, "Use stop Loss Trigger")
StopTrailTrigger    = input.float(0.5, "SL Trigger (%)",minval=0,step=0.5) * 0.01
useTP               = input(true, "Use take profit")
ProfitTrailPerc     = input.float(0.5, "Trailing Profit (%)",minval=0,step=0.5) * 0.01
use_TP_Trigger      = input(false, "Use Take Profit Trigger")
takeProfitTrigger   = input.float(1.0, "Take Profit Trigger (%)",minval=0,step=0.5) * 0.01                              
//====================================================================================================

FiboCalc(price1, price2, level) =>
    range12 = math.abs(price1 - price2)
    if level == 1
        price1
    if level > 1
        if price1 > price2
            price1+range12*(level-1)
        else
            price2-range12*(level-1)
    if level < 1 and level > 0
        if price1 > price2
            price1-range12*(1-level)
        else
            price2+range12*(1-level)

redCandle = close < open
greenCandle = open < close

lowWick = math.min(open, close) - low
highWick = high - math.max(open, close)
body = math.max(open, close) - math.min(open, close)

candleCond = redCandle[2] and greenCandle[1] and pesado[1]
volumCond = volume[2] > volume[1]
bodyCond = body[2] < body[1]
wickCond = highWick[1] > lowWick[1] and highWick[2] < lowWick[2] and highWick[1] < body[1] and lowWick[2] < body[2]

long1 = true
long2 = true

if not candleCond
    long1:=false
    long2:=false

if not volumCond
    long1:=false
    long2:=false

if not bodyCond
    long1:=false
    long2:=false
    
if not pesado[1]
    long1 :=false
else
    long2 := false

if not wickCond
    long1:=false
    long2:=false

var float pendingOrder = close*3
short = false
long = false

var float entry_price = na
var isShort = false
var isLong = false
var isOP = false
var isPO = false

placeLimit = true
if long1 and not isOP
    pendingOrder := (open[1])
    isPO:= true
else if long2 and not isOP
    pendingOrder := FiboCalc(close[1], open[1], 0.618)
    isPO:= true
else
    placeLimit := false
    
plotshape(placeLimit? high + ta.atr(30) :na, title="limit", text='Limit', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.silver, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

    
// plot(entry_price)
long := low <= pendingOrder and isPO and not isOP
short := false

if short or long
    isOP := true
    if short
        isShort := true
    if long 
        isLong := true
        isPO := false
        long := true
        entry_price := pendingOrder
        
StopLossPriceTrigger = 0.0
StopLossPriceTrigger := if (use_SL_Trigger)
    if isShort
        entry_price * (1 + StopTrailTrigger) 
    else if isLong
        entry_price * (1 - StopTrailTrigger)
else
    -1

var SL_Trigger_Long_HIT = false
SL_Trigger_Long_HIT := useSL and use_SL_Trigger and isLong and low <= StopLossPriceTrigger

var SL_Trigger_Short_HIT = false
SL_Trigger_Short_HIT := useSL and use_SL_Trigger and isShort and high >= StopLossPriceTrigger

display_long_SL_trigger     = useSL and isLong and use_SL_Trigger 
 and SL_Trigger_Long_HIT == false and StopLossPriceTrigger != -1
display_short_SL_trigger    = useSL and isShort and use_SL_Trigger 
 and SL_Trigger_Short_HIT == false and StopLossPriceTrigger != -1
display_SL_trigger          = display_long_SL_trigger or display_short_SL_trigger
// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0, shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if useSL and isLong
    stopValue = low * (1 - StopTrailPerc)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

shortStopPrice := if useSL and isShort
    stopValue = high * (1 + StopTrailPerc)
    math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    99999

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//*** STOP LOSS HIT CONDITIONS  ***//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cond_long_stop_loss_hit  = useSL  and ta.crossunder(low, longStopPrice[1]) 
 and (SL_Trigger_Long_HIT or use_SL_Trigger == false)
cond_short_stop_loss_hit = useSL  and ta.crossover(high, shortStopPrice[1]) 

takeprofitPriceTrigger = 0.0
takeprofitPriceTrigger := if (use_TP_Trigger)
    if (isLong)
        entry_price * (1 + takeProfitTrigger) 
    else if (isShort)
        entry_price * (1 - takeProfitTrigger)
else
    -1

var TP_Trigger_Long_HIT = false
TP_Trigger_Long_HIT := useTP and use_TP_Trigger and isLong and high >= takeprofitPriceTrigger


var TP_Trigger_Short_HIT = false
TP_Trigger_Short_HIT := useTP and use_TP_Trigger and isShort and low <= takeprofitPriceTrigger


display_long_TP_trigger     = useTP and isLong  and TP_Trigger_Long_HIT == false 
 and takeprofitPriceTrigger != -1
display_short_TP_trigger    = useTP and isShort and TP_Trigger_Short_HIT == false 
 and takeprofitPriceTrigger != -1
display_TP_trigger          = display_long_TP_trigger or display_short_TP_trigger


//
// @hugo: Will display the TP trigger as long as not hit
// once the TP trigger is hit, the TP trailing will activate
// plot(display_TP_trigger ? takeprofitPriceTrigger : na, title='takeprofitPriceTrigger', transp=0, color=color.orange, 
//  style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3)

longTrailTP= 0.0, shortTrailTP = 0.0

// Trailing Profit
// Start trailing once trigger is reached
longTrailTP := if useTP and isLong 
    tpValue = high * (1 + ProfitTrailPerc)
    math.max(tpValue, longTrailTP[1])
else
    0

shortTrailTP := if useTP and isShort
    tpValue = low * (1 - ProfitTrailPerc)
    math.min(tpValue, shortTrailTP[1])
else
    99999

// plot(StopLossPriceTrigger)
// plot(takeprofitPriceTrigger)
// plot(longTrailTP, title='debug longTrailTP', transp=100)

// plot(SL, title='debug shortTrailTP', transp=0)
// plot(shortTrailTP, title='debug shortTrailTP', transp=100)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//*** TRAILING TAKE PROFIT HIT CONDITIONS TO BE USED IN ALERTS  ***//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//
// @hugo: I use crossover/crossunder for the alerts to trigger the events only once
cond_long_trail_tp_hit      = useTP  and isLong  and ta.crossover(high, longTrailTP[1]) 
 and (TP_Trigger_Long_HIT or use_TP_Trigger == false)
cond_short_trail_tp_hit     = useTP  and isShort  and ta.crossunder(low, shortTrailTP[1]) 
 and (TP_Trigger_Short_HIT or use_TP_Trigger == false)
// 
shortclose = isOP and isShort and (cond_short_trail_tp_hit or TP_Trigger_Short_HIT or cond_short_stop_loss_hit or SL_Trigger_Short_HIT)
longclose = isOP and isLong and (cond_long_trail_tp_hit or TP_Trigger_Long_HIT or cond_long_stop_loss_hit or SL_Trigger_Long_HIT)

if shortclose or longclose
    isOP := false
    if longclose
        isLong := false
    if shortclose
        isShort := false

alertcondition(long,"Long Alert")
alertcondition(short,"Short Alert")
alertcondition(longclose, "Close Long Alert")
alertcondition(shortclose, "Close Short Alert")



plotshape(short? high + ta.atr(30) * 2 :na, title="short", text='Short', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(shortclose? low - ta.atr(30) :na, title='close', text='close', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(long? low - ta.atr(30) * 2 :na, title="Long", text='Long', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(longclose? high + ta.atr(30)  :na, title='close', text='close', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

plot( pendingOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed this by not using `ta.atr(30)` on plotting. instead of that, I adding one more line to handle this:

```
atrSpacing = ta.atr(30)
plotshape(short? high + atrSpacing * 2 :na, title="short", text='Short', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(shortclose? low - atrSpacing :na, title='close', text='close', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(long? low - atrSpacing * 2 :na, title="Long", text='Long', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(longclose? high + atrSpacing :na, title='close', text='close', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```